# How to handle "Memory quota exceeded" in heroku app developed using streamlit and PyTorch?

Tags: python, heroku, pytorch, streamlit

I have been developing a style transfer image application using streamlit and PyTorch. The app is facing memory quota exceeded whenever high resolution image is stylized(using the app). How do I reduce the app size(its around 200+ mb)?

App code : https://github.com/pr2tik1/deep-stylize-image

App deployment : https://deep-style-images.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about slug size so it is nothing to do with your application size, it is about RAM you are using. Since you are using free dyno you can not process high resolution images.

You will require minimum performance dyno in my opinion since image computation require pretty much memory.

Comment: Thanks for answering!  Also, is there any way caching can help in this scenario? The @streamlit.cache mechanism?

Comment: It will help only when somebody process same input which streamlit faced before. So cache will improve general performance but in your scenerio you will still require enough ram to process high resolution images. I advice you to use AWS , you can easly scale your app up and down to find exact requirement. If answer is helpfull please accept it! Happy coding!